# How to use Suspense with React-Router-Dom v6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router

I'm trying to migrate react-router-dom from v5 to v6 and I'm having a trouble, here is my implementation with using `Suspense`

```
<Suspense
   fallback={
     <div className="center-div">
        <LoadingDots />
     </div>
   }
>
    <Routes>
        {routes.map((route, index) => (
           <Route
              path={route.path}
              key={route.path}
              element={lazy(() => import("./features/apps/AppsListPage"))} //it is route.component but for simplify example i'm show it like this
          />
        ))}
    </Routes>
</Suspense>
```

can someone tell me why browser return me this kind of error?

```
index.tsx:13 Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, _payload, _init}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

I think that it caused by using `lazy` in `element` prop, but can i fix this?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: See if the [Lazy Loading](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/examples/lazy-loading) example helps you.

Comment: Moving the lazy import out of the router and rendering the component doesn't work for you? It seems that `lazy(() => import("./features/apps/AppsListPage"))` isn't a valid React component, i.e. it isn't a `ReactNode`. The `element` prop expects to receive JSX.

Comment: hmmm... yes it working but it weird cause i have to use it like this `element={<route.component />}`

Comment: `route.component` is `lazy(()=>...`

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now. So is there an issue with using `element={<route.component />}`? It seems you said it's working.

Comment: right now it's working but i think that it is a little bit weird

Comment: <Header /> compiles to React.createElement(Header)
<div></div> compiles to React.createElement("div")
so it is either a Function or string
therefore route.component=Header or route.component="div"
both works fine.

Comment: Typically people call that part outside the Routes function such as:
const lazyComponent = React.lazy(() => import('path to lazy component'));

Then put suspense inside the <routes> but having routes.map nested inside suspense.